# Django REST Framework: change the url to the .list() method only in a ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm making a registration api, and as I followed the docs, it recommended the use of `ViewSets`, so i used a `ModelViewSet`, now if i `POST` to the url `'*/api/register/'`, I'll make a registration if provided valid fields (using `.create()` method), which is perfect for my case just what i needed.
but when I want to list all the users for the admin, the request should be to the same url with a `GET` method, which is a bit weird to access `'*/api/register/'` to see the users...
so I wanted to change the url for the `.list()` method to be something like '`*/api/users/'`, but I can't find how to do that.
here is what i'm doing until now:

apis.py:

```
class RegisterApi(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return [permissions.AllowAny()]
        else:
            return [permissions.IsAdminUser()]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if response:
            response.data = dict(status=True, code=1)
        return response
```

urls.py:

```
api_router = SimpleRouter()
api_router.register('register', apis.RegisterApi, basename='users')

extra_urls = [path('login/', apis.LoginApi.as_view()), ]

urlpatterns = [
    # views urls
    path('', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('dashboard/', views.Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('register/', views.RegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),

    # api urls
    path('api/', include(extra_urls + api_router.urls)),
 ]
```

Any hints about this?

Comment: I would have ViewSet for a User model and a separate View for registration. Maybe an registration would be an action inside UserViewSet

Answer (score 0):

You should rename the api to `/users`. Then the http method `POST` is for creating (or registering) a new User, the `GET` method is for listing Users.

Read more about restful api naming convention, for example: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/